# How to determine whether a 32-bit/64-bit value has a certain 16-bit value?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

## Questions

Consider the following 32-bit and 64-bit values:

```c
  uint32_t iVal32 = 0x AB CD 12 34;
  uint64_t iVal64 = 0x AB CD 12 34 56 78 CA BE;
```

1. How to determine whether `iVal32` contains a certain 16-bit (word) value? <strike>Let's say `0xCD12`.</strike>
2. How to determine whether `iVal64` contains a certain 16-bit (word) value? <strike>Let's say `0x3456`.</strike>

#### Update 1 (added later)

- <strike>`0xCD12`</strike> A word value that is to be checked might be anywhere in `iVal32` in every word boundary.
- <strike>`0x3456`</strike> A word value that is to be checked might be anywhere in `iVal64` in every word boundary.

#### Update 2 (added later)

I admit a ridiculous mistake in the question. In my previous example, the word values to be checked were not in word boundaries in `iVal32` and `iVal64`. Therefore, my correction are:

- For `iVal32`, a word value to be checked can be either `0xABCD` or `0x1234`. Thus, for example, `0xCD12` shouldn't be found in `iVal32`.
- For `iVal64`, a word value to be checked can be one of the following: `0xABCD` or `0x1234` or `0x5678` or `0xCABE`. Thus, for example, `0xCD12` or `0x3456` or `0x78CA` shouldn't be found in `iVal64`.

## Remarks

- Solutions are intended to be used in a function that searches for a 16-bit character in a Unicode string. In x86, the function reads two characters at a time; and in x64, the function reads four characters at a time.
- I ask this because I noticed that the implementation of glibc [strchr()](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/strchr.c) (that works for 8-bit character) tries to test a longword at a time, but I didn't understand the code well.

Comment: `iVal32 == (iVal32)iVal16`? It would be much easier to use unsigned.

Comment: @Olaf - I have updated both to be unsigned.

Comment: @Jeff: These are no valid strings!

Comment: That actually included a bit sarcasm. You did not even define "contain" precisely. And your examples do not add to clarity.

Comment: As @Olaf said, could you define "contain" more precisely? For instance, does `0xAB12CD34 >> 1;` contain `0xAB12`?

Comment: @Olaf - Good point.  strrchr is out.  but still a perfect candidate for SSE2 / AVX.  Or AVX2 if you don't care about older processors.

Comment: @Jeff: My mobile does not hav any of those. Nor does my embedded CPU.

Comment: @Olaf - Oops, I have just corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: While you can do this with bitmanipulation, it's annoying. Can you clarify whether SSE is allowed and if so which versions?

Comment: No, you have not. Please think it over first, then write it down.

Comment: @Olaf - Just imagine that 0xCD12 and 0x3456 are 16-bit characters stored in memory.

Comment: there's an algorithm to check if "a word has a byte equal to n" here http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord

Comment: i am very interested in what function will behave differently out of the box in different architecture?

Comment: @harold - Since this is about bitwise manipulation (not about speed optimization), I think SSE is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Aeoliyan sure, if you want it to be. You're the OP after all. But it wouldn't have been the first time that someone asked for a bithack but actually wanted a speed optimization.

Comment: i think you can try this: `(value & iVal32) ^ value == 0` return `1` if it satisfies your requirement. and perform another time of `<<` to make sure this for higher bits.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - Yes, your link is a good starting point.

Comment: You can combine that check-for-zero with `x ^ (test * 0x00010001)` (that's 32bit, extend the obvious way)

Comment: Do it with bit shifting and AND operations. Don't over shift though: that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Should the bit pattern be aligned on byte boundaries?

Comment: your could use memcmp() in a loop, that starts with the first byte if the 32 or 64 bit memory entity and step forward one byte on each iteration of the loop and compare 2 bytes at a time.  Note: you may have to pay attention to the Endianness of the underlying architecture

Comment: @DanielJour - See my update.

Comment: @user3629249 - Yes, thanks for your suggestion, I agree `memcmp()` can be used. However, solutions to this question still have advantages to understand what is behind the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool contains (uint32_t haystack, uint16_t needle)
{
    return ((haystack & 0xffff) == needle) ||
           (((haystack >> 16) & 0xffff) == needle);
}

bool contains (uint64_t haystack, uint16_t needle)
{
    return ((haystack & 0xffff) == needle) ||
           (((haystack >> 16) & 0xffff) == needle) ||
           (((haystack >> 32) & 0xffff) == needle) ||
           (((haystack >> 48) & 0xffff) == needle);
}
```

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Would you adapt your code to follow my latest update? Sorry for inconvenience. +1

Answer (score 1):

Not completely clear what the OP wants but given the description and subsequent comments, something along the lines of this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;

bool contains(uint16_t item, uint32_t source);
bool contains(uint16_t item, uint64_t source);

int main()
{
    uint32_t iVal32 = 0xABCD1234;
    uint64_t iVal64 = 0xABCD12345678CABELL;

    cout << contains(0x1234, iVal32) << endl;
    cout << contains(0xABCD, iVal32) << endl;

    cout << contains(0xABCD, iVal64) << endl;
    cout << contains(0x1234, iVal64) << endl;
    cout << contains(0x5678, iVal64) << endl;
    cout << contains(0xCABE, iVal64) << endl;   
    return 0;
}

bool contains(uint16_t item, uint32_t source)
{
    for (int i = 16 ; i >= 0 ; i -= 16)
    {
        if (((source << i) >> 16) == item)
        {
           return true;
        }    
    }
    return false;
}

bool contains(uint16_t item, uint64_t source)
{
    for(int i = 48 ; i >= 0 ; i -= 16)
    {
        if (((source << i) >> 48) == item)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @P_Hinker - See my latest update. Sorry for inconvenience. +1

Comment: @P_Hinker - I will upvote you later when my point is at least 15. It turns out that is the rule here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution for 32bit.
`find_pos` returns the bit position of the 16bit value in the 32bit value,
or `-1` if the 32bit value does not contain the 16bit value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t iVal32 = 0xABCD1234;
uint64_t iVal64 = 0xABCD12345678CABE;

int find_pos(uint32_t value, uint16_t pattern)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i+=4) {
        uint32_t v = (value & (0xFFFF << i));
        uint32_t p = (pattern << i);
        if (v == p)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main ()
{
    printf("i = %i\n", find_pos(iVal32, 0xCD12));

    return 0;
}
```

**update:**

Here is a possible solution for 32bit and 64bit, using a macro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t iVal32 = 0xABCD1234;
uint64_t iVal64 = 0xABCD12345678CABE;

#define find_pos(value, pattern, width)             \
({                                                  \
    int i;                                          \
    int found = 0;                                  \
                                                    \
    for (i = 0; i < width; i+=4) {                  \
        typeof(value) v = (value & (0xFFFF << i));  \
        typeof(value) p = (pattern << i);           \
        if (v == p) {                               \
            found = 1;                              \
            break;                                  \
        }                                           \
    }                                               \
                                                    \
    if (!found)                                     \
        i = -1;                                     \
    i;                                              \
})

#define find_pos32(value, pattern) \
    find_pos(value, pattern, 32)

#define find_pos64(value, pattern) \
    find_pos(value, pattern, 64)

int main ()
{
    printf("i = %i\n", find_pos32(iVal32, 0xCD12));
    printf("i = %i\n", find_pos64(iVal64, 0x678C));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll test it, but the time now is already dawn in my country, so I have to sleep now. I'll come back soon. :-)

Comment: Would you adapt your code to follow my latest update? Sorry for inconvenience. +1

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand what you mean. Do you get what you expect if you change `i+=4` to `i+=16`?

Comment: Yes, one word (16-bit) for each test, that was I meant. However, I think the pattern matching test should be from left to right instead. Perhaps, the `0xFFFF` should be changed to `0xFFFF0000`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will upvote you later when my points achieve 15. I accept David Schwartz's answer because he done it without a looping.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation of David's answer, non-branching.

```
bool contains (uint32_t haystack, uint16_t needle)
{
    uint32_t h1 = (haystack ^ needle) & 0xFFFF;
    haystack >>= 16;
    uint32_t h2 = haystack ^ needle; // No need for mask.
    // If and only if needle was in haystack, h1 or h2 will now be 0
    return (h1*h2) == 0;
}
```

Two XOR's, one shift, one mask, one multiplication and a compare that's probably free. Only 3 registers needed. The obvious extension to x64 calculates `h1*h2*h3*h4` but it might be more efficient to calculate a running product, so we don't need registers for the 4 intermediate results. (A decent optimizer will also do this).

Since there's no shortcut evaluation, this may sometimes take more instructions, but the lack of shortcut evaluation also means there's no branch. I'll bet that for string searching this is a net win.

Going a bit off-topic, the question mentions x86. SSE is the logical option there, especially for 64 bits.

Comment: I'm amazed by your clever solution. By the way, instead of `return (h1 * h2) == 0;` I think `return (h1 & h2) == 0;` should be faster, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Aeoliyan: It's faster but wrong. 1100 & 0011 == 0000.

Comment: Wouldn't return (h1==0)|(h2==0) be faster?

Comment: @warren: That's three operations: two compares and an or. Although it's not unreasonable for the compiler to turn both into the same binary.